# Run an SSH command at shutdown using systemd

Tags: networking, ssh, shutdown, systemd

I need to run an ssh command at shutdown/reboot in my Ubuntu 18.04 PC

I struggled reading infinite posts pretending to solve this issue but no way.

I wrote this service in /etc/systemd/system/mydown.service

```
[Unit]
Description=launcher at system shutdown
Requires=network.target
After=network.target
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/tux/bin/mylauncher.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the script

```
# mylauncher.sh
scp -v TEST tux@192.168.1.254:/home/tux
```

And activated it

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable mydown.service --now
sudo systemctl status mydown.service
```

However it is not able to run any SSH or network command because when it is called seems that network is not available.

Any idea to solve it?